# AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using

Tags: macos, apache

i try to install apache via homebrew.

when i try to start httpd by

```
brew services start httpd
```

i receive this message

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Samanthas-MacBook-Pro-2.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
> (13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log.
> AH00015: Unable to open logs

[image]

I didn't find a tutorial which works.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: The error message in the question title is harmless (and has an easy fix, quoted in the message itself).

Comment: did you manage to get it ?